# Configuration of a pie chart and a legend in the dojo

Tags: javascript, json, charts, dojo, legend

Sorry for my english.

I want to program a web application where a user fills out a form and sends it to the server. The server sends the requested data as a JSON object. With these data, a diagram and a legend with Dojo to create.
The graph and legend look like this:

http://www.gm.fh-koeln.de/~mi932/chart_with_legend.PNG

1 Question: In the legend, the number 47, 14, 11, ... are not displayed, but a given text to be displayed, which is located in the JSON object. How do I do that?

2 Question: I use the Claro theme of the dojo. But the subject has only 5 colors, then repeat the colors. How can I do that every sector of a circle given a different color?

3 Question: If the user makes a new query, the old chart and the old legend will be deleted and the new chart and legend. This only works with the chart. The legend will be hidden and not displayed. What am I doing wrong?

Client looks like this:

```
<script>
require(["dojo/dom", 
         "dojo/on", 
     "dojo/request", 
     "dojo/dom-form",
     "statsDiagramme/kreisDiagramm",
     "statsDiagramme/stabDiagramm",
     "dojo/json", 
     "dojox/json/query", 
     "dijit/Dialog", 
     "dijit/form/Button",
      "dojo/domReady!"],

function(dom, on, request, domForm, kreisdiagramm, stabdiagramm, json){

     var form = dom.byId('sqlOptForm');      
     on(form, "submit", function(evt){                      
         evt.stopPropagation();         
         evt.preventDefault();      

         request.post("ServletStatsSQLOPT", {       

    data: domForm.toObject("sqlOptForm"),   
    handleAs: "json"

     }).then(function(response){

    var fehler = dojox.json.query("fehlermeldung", response);

    if(fehler == ""){   
                                dojo.html._emptyNode("statsKreisDiagramm");
                                dojo.html._emptyNode("statsStabDiagramm");
                                dojo.html._emptyNode("legende");

                                stabdiagramm.setStabDiagramm(response); 
                                kreisdiagramm.setKreisDiagramm(response);
                                dom.byId("statsKreisDiagramm").style.visibility = 'visible';
                                dom.byId("statsStabDiagramm").style.visibility = 'hidden';
                                dom.byId("statsMenuButton").style.visibility = 'visible';
                                dom.byId("legende").style.visibility = 'visible';                   

    }
    else {                  
        // ERROR 

    }

    }, function(error) {    
        // ERROR 

        });
        });
    }
    );
</script>
```

The chart is created as:

```
define([
"dojox/charting/Chart",
"dojox/charting/themes/Claro",
"dojox/charting/plot2d/Pie",
"dojox/charting/action2d/Tooltip",
"dojox/charting/action2d/MoveSlice",
"dojox/charting/widget/Legend",
"dojox/charting/plot2d/Markers",
"dojox/charting/widget/Legend",
"dojox/charting/axis2d/Default",

"dojo/domReady!"
], 
function(Chart, theme, PiePlot, Tooltip, MoveSlice, Legend){

    return{
        setKreisDiagramm: function(response) {

            var daten = new Array(response.summeArray.length);          
            // response => JSON-Objekt
            for(var i=0; i < response.summeArray.length; i++) {
                daten[i] = { x: 1, y: response.summeArray[i].summe };   
            }

            var kreisDiag = new Chart("statsKreisDiagramm");        

            kreisDiag.setTheme(theme);          


            kreisDiag.addPlot("default", {
                type: PiePlot,                  
                radius: 180,
                fontColor: "black",
                labelOffset: 30,                
                markers: true
            });

            kreisDiag.addSeries("Zusammenfassung", daten);      

            var tip = new Tooltip(kreisDiag, "default");        

            var mag = new MoveSlice(kreisDiag,"default");       

            kreisDiag.render();

            var legend = new Legend({ chart: kreisDiag, horizontal: false },   "legende");


        }
    };
}
);
```

Can any one help me?
I thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a legend is present, it must first be destroyed.
The question 3 can be solved:

```
var legend = dijit.byId("legende");
if (legend) {
  legend.destroyRecursive(true);
}

var legend = new dojox.charting.widget.Legend({ chart: kreisDiag, horizontal: false }, "legende");
```

Answer (score 1):

For question 2:

You can define your own theme or use a predefined dojo theme for your pie-chart.

You can find an Example and Explanations here:
http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/charting/ under the Point Chart Themes

Here's the API for the themes:

http://dojotoolkit.org/api/dojox/charting/themes/Minty

and a Preview for them:

http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.5.0/dojo-release-1.5.0/dojox/charting/tests/theme_preview.html

Maybe this helps a bit.

Regards, Miriam

Comment: thank you. I have already done. Does anyone know how I can solve the questions 1 and 3?

Comment: When I use the statement "daten[i] = { x: 1, y: response.summeArray[i].summe, text: response.summeArray[i].inhalt };" in the for loop, then only the text is displayed, but not the number.
http://www.gm.fh-koeln.de/~mi932/chart_with_legend1.PNG

Comment: Hi! Have you checked the submitted Data with an alert? Are there any entries in response.summeArray[i].summe?

Comment: Hi, yes, I've checked and everything is correct. In the diagram, the totals are also displayed correctly. Only in the legend text (element "Inhalt" from Json object) to be displayed and not the totals. This is the JSON object:http://www.gm.fh-koeln.de/~mi932/json.PNG